# Finding a point on the bisectrix

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, angle, points

I have this problem : 
3 points A, B, C that make an angle < 180 degrees. The points are given as (x, y) pairs.
I have to find a point placed on the bisectrix of the angle, in the outside of the ABC triangle, and the distance between that point and B point to be D.

Comment: Two points: i) Is this homework? ii) The question doesn't contain any programming/software element. Better post this on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 2. I have to make a flash game (so it is related to programming), and i need to draw a band that goes around some points. And I need that point located on the bisectrix, to know where the band corners will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locus of a point that's a distance *D* from a point B is a circle with radius *D* centred at B. So intersect the angle bisector with this circle. There will be two points of intersection; pick one that's outside the ABC triangle.